# How to change cell background color in numbers according to some rules?

Tags: numbers

Making it simple, using Numbers, how can you set up the following:

If number is positive make background cell green, else make it red.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Select the cell where you want to apply the rule. From the menu choose *Format* -> *Show Conditional Format rules*. A window opens which allows you to enter rules.

For example (this is the rule you asked for):
[image]